# Tap on UIWebView to transition to different viewController

Tags: ios, swift, uiwebview

I have a webview inside view controller "A", is it possible to tap on web view and seaque to view controller "B"? 
I have tried do following

```
 @IBOutlet weak var mainWebView: UIWebView!
 let tapUIWebView = UITapGestureRecognizer()

  override func viewDidLoad() {
  super.viewDidLoad()

  tapUIWebView.addTarget(self, action: "webViewTapped")
  mainWebView.userInteractionEnabled = true
  mainWebView.addGestureRecognizer(tapUIWebView)  

  func webViewTapped(){
        println("Tapped")
    }

}
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

1) Use a `UITapGestureRecognizer`, create the instance.

2) Attach it to the webview.

3) Implement the action method that handles the gesture.

4) Since`UIWebView` already recognises a touch, you need to also take care that your recognizer does the job first. And you decide what to do with the touch.

5) If it suits you, you can disable handling the tap in the built-in recogniser completely.

Comment: I'm really new to IOS development can you show some example in swift? Thank you

Comment: If you are new, it is all the more a reason for YOU to write the code. That way you will learn things properly. Start with step 1), instantiate the class in your view controller. If you will get stuck already in step 1) then you need to get back to fundamentals at developer.apple.com.

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/EventHandling/Conceptual/EventHandlingiPhoneOS/Introduction/Introduction.html

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TheBasics.html